# sampling data based on posterior joint-probabilities

Tags: python, r, random, statistics, probability

I have a dataset and would like get a sample based on probabilities that I manually set.

Example: *(id = user, score(sort by desc), b1-b6(dummy variable)), **1 represents users have this feature, 0 otherwise***

`id  score b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6`

`1    0.99  1  0  0  0  1  0`

`2    0.98  1  0  0  0  0  0`

`3    0.97  1  1  1  0  1  1`

`4    0.96  0  1  0  0  0  0`

A parameter set (**p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6**) is given that controls the proportion of users having this feature in columns (b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6) respectively

Let's see I set p1 = 0.1, p2 = 0.2, p3 = 0.9, p4 = 0.32, p5 = 0.2, p6 = 0.21
And  it's expected to sample from the dataset whose distribution is approximately follow the p1-p6 values.

**about 10% of users have 1 in b1, 20% users have 1 in b2 and so on)**

Problem is the original dataset has its distributions across b1 to b6, and how to 
get a sample from it, which has the distributions that follows the p1-p6 values

Any thoughts would be appreciated

**UPDATES**
It's to draw a sample from a large dataset (1k sample from 1000k) that follows the distributions (p1,p2 etc.),instead of simulating phony data

**Approach 1**: It may be solved by repeating random sample. and using the closest one(need resampling or iteration tricks).

**Approach 2**: using linear optimisation algorithm(may be complicated, as 2^6 possibilities, and needs to solve large equations)

Comment: Couldn't you just sample the `b` vectors and `cbind` them?

Comment: `as.numeric(sapply(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0.32, 0.2, 0.21), rbernoulli, n = 1))`

Comment: @RobJensen not base R, what package? Why not base?

Comment: `purrr` package, see `??rbernoulli`.

Comment: henry, there's a slight difference between *"proportion of users"* and *"probability each user is true"*. With non-large populations, there will almost certainly be a difference. Which is it?

Comment: Didn't notice `rbernoulli` is not a base R or stats function. You can also do `sapply(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0.32, 0.2, 0.21), rbinom, size = 1, n = 1)`

Comment: `sapply(c(.1, .2, .9, .32, .2, .21), function(x) sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = T, prob = c(1-x, x)))` would also do the trick (100 rows in this case).

Comment: Do you want a sample (extracted from your dataset), or do you want to simulate a new sample ?

Comment: @r2evans I guess it's *proportion of users* because I expected to draw 10% of users that have 1 in column b1.

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington, I want a sample whose users's feature(b1-b6) follow the approximate distribution I set(p1,p2 and so on). I guess you cannot get a sample that follows exactly the parameters you set, only approximately

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Do you want completely simulated data (as suggested by some commentaries above, or do you need to extracts lines from your dataset ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington, excuse me, but what's is difference between these two

Comment: A sample of your data : all lines in your sample exists in your original dataset (and in fact comes from your data). A complete simulation : lines in your sample are just comming from simulation, and may be or may not exist in your original dataset.

Comment: @ MrSmithGoesToWashington. It should be the first case (get a sample that comes from original dataset).

Answer (score 0):

Henry, as suggested in the comments, there are two general ways to produce data like this. One is to calculate the *"probability that each cell will be 0 or 1"*, and the other is *"random sampling of the vector such that `n`% are selected"*. The two are completely different (at least in not-large scales).

A demonstration. Base probabilities/proportions:

```
probs <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0.32, 0.2, 0.21)
names(probs) <- paste0('b', seq_along(probs))

set.seed(2)
n <- 1e5
dat <- cbind.data.frame(sapply(probs, function(p) {
  sample(0:1, size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1-p, p))
}))
head(dat)
#   b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6
# 1  0  0  1  1  0  1
# 2  0  0  0  1  1  0
# 3  0  0  1  1  0  0
# 4  0  0  1  0  0  0
# 5  1  0  1  0  0  0
# 6  1  0  1  0  1  0
colSums(dat)/n
#      b1      b2      b3      b4      b5      b6 
# 0.10125 0.20100 0.89975 0.32013 0.20182 0.20827
```

This looks about right, the proportions are pretty close. Now let's look at a smaller population:

```
set.seed(2)
n <- 10
dat <- cbind.data.frame(sapply(probs, function(p) {
  sample(0:1, size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1-p, p))
}))
dat
#    b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6
# 1   0  0  1  0  1  0
# 2   0  0  1  0  0  0
# 3   0  0  1  1  0  0
# 4   0  0  1  1  0  1
# 5   1  0  1  0  1  0
# 6   1  1  1  0  0  1
# 7   0  1  1  1  1  0
# 8   0  0  1  0  0  1
# 9   0  0  0  0  0  0
# 10  0  0  1  0  1  0
colSums(dat)/n
#  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6 
# 0.2 0.2 0.9 0.3 0.4 0.3
```

That's not even "close" for some of the columns, even within rounding. This is the problem. For this, our "view" of the randomness is effectively "one cell at a time", instead of "one column at a time".

Okay, let's try to do it one column at a time.

```
set.seed(2)
n <- 10
dat <- cbind.data.frame(sapply(probs, function(p) {
  i <- sample(n, size=n*p)
  vec <- integer(n)
  vec[i] <- 1
  vec
}))
dat
#    b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6
# 1   0  0  1  0  0  0
# 2   1  0  1  1  0  0
# 3   0  0  1  0  0  1
# 4   0  0  0  1  0  0
# 5   0  0  1  0  0  1
# 6   0  1  1  0  0  0
# 7   0  0  1  0  0  0
# 8   0  1  1  1  0  0
# 9   0  0  1  0  1  0
# 10  0  0  1  0  1  0
colSums(dat)/n
#  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6 
# 0.1 0.2 0.9 0.3 0.2 0.2
```

This looks much closer, within rounding. (You may choose to use `size=ceiling(n*p)` or perhaps `size=max(1,n*p)` to handle low probabilities, as otherwise it is truncated, not rounded.) Notice that with larger populations it will still behave as well as the implementation above.

Luckily, they both perform about the same, so you can choose whichever meets your sampling requirements.

```
library(microbenchmark)
n <- 10
microbenchmark(
  probability = cbind.data.frame(sapply(probs, function(p) { sample(0:1, size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1-p, p)) })),
  proportion = cbind.data.frame(sapply(probs, function(p) { i <- sample(n, size=n*p); vec <- integer(n); vec[i] <- 1; vec; }))
)
# Unit: microseconds
#         expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
#  probability  99.191 104.6620 126.0461 114.5075 139.4880 384.001   100
#   proportion 106.485 113.2315 131.9465 122.7135 149.1515 213.334   100
n <- 1e5
...
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  probability 254.9634 298.0875 349.3892 331.2826 364.0245 680.3098   100
#   proportion 281.7271 351.9515 418.4833 386.5976 449.6032 931.0893   100
```

Comment: the demonstrations were aimed to simulate new data. But, What I expected is to get a sample from the existing dataset. that is, it has prior probabilities regarding to b1-b6(prior: p1 = 0.2, p2 = 0.3, and I want to get a sample with posterior probabilities : p1 = 0.3, p2 = 0.5 etc). Sorry about the confusion, and I didn't notice this difference. Thanks  @MrSmithGoesToWashington for pointing it out