# Simulating data sample

Tags: r, statistics, probability, sampling

I have the following probabilities for each group, and each group represents a certain range of values. My goal is to simulate 1,234 rows of data that corresponds with the groups and percentages:

```
ages = c(21:29, 30:39,40:49, 50:59, 60:69, 70:79, 80:89, 90:99)
age_probs = c(10.85,12.64,14.02,25.00,19.01,11.45,7.01,0.01) / 100

age_bins = sapply(list(21:29, 30:39,40:49, 50:59, 60:69, 70:79, 80:89, 90:99), length)
age_weighted = rep(age_probs/age_bins, age_bins)

set.seed(1)
n = 1234
data = data.frame(ID = sample(n),
                  Age = sample(ages, size = n, prob = age_weighted, replace = TRUE))
```

However, the percentages of the data don't match and is too different at times (I assume because the data isn't big enough). I found another [post, which mentions that this happens because this, our "view" of the randomness is effectively "one cell at a time", instead of "one column at a time".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424044/sampling-data-based-on-posterior-joint-probabilities) This is in reference to the sample() function.

How can I change my sample function to better represent the population percentages?

Oh and here is how I checked the columns of my data frame

```
to_export = data[order(data$ID),]


for (i in (1:length(to_export$Age))) {
  if (to_export$Age[i] >= 21 & to_export$Age[i] <= 29) to_export$block[i] = "21-29"
  if (to_export$Age[i] >= 30 & to_export$Age[i] <= 39) to_export$block[i] = "30-39"
  if (to_export$Age[i] >= 40 & to_export$Age[i] <= 49) to_export$block[i] = "40-49"
  if (to_export$Age[i] >= 50 & to_export$Age[i] <= 59) to_export$block[i] = "50-59"
  if (to_export$Age[i] >= 60 & to_export$Age[i] <= 69) to_export$block[i] = "60-69"
  if (to_export$Age[i] >= 70 & to_export$Age[i] <= 79) to_export$block[i] = "70-79"
  if (to_export$Age[i] >= 80 & to_export$Age[i] <= 89) to_export$block[i] = "80-89"
  if (to_export$Age[i] >= 90) to_export$block[i] = "90+"

}

#to_export

age_table = to_export %>% group_by(block) %>% summarise(percentage = round(n()/1234 * 100,2))

age_table
```

Comment: Just a hint: Your checks (multiple `if`-clauses inside a `for`-loop) can be replaced by `mutate` combined with `case_when`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a small redesign. I'm using `dplyr` and `ggplot` but basically they aren't needed:

```r
set.seed(1)
n = 1234

# Definition of the age buckets
ages = c("21:29", "30:39","40:49", "50:59", "60:69", "70:79", "80:89", "90:99")

# probability for each bucket
age_probs = c(10.85,12.64,14.02,25.00,19.01,11.45,7.01,0.01)

# normalise the probabilities since they don't add up to 1
c_age_probs = cumsum(age_probs)/sum(age_probs)

# create the data.frame
data = data.frame(ID = 1:n,
                  Age = ages[findInterval(runif(n), c_age_probs) + 1])

# plotting the data
ggplot(data, aes(x=Age)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

The datas plot looks okay, according to the given probabilities. Let's take a look at the percentages:

```
# getting the percentage
data %>%
  group_by(Age) %>%
  summarise(percentage = n()/n)

#   A tibble: 7 x 2
#   Age   percentage
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 21:29     0.0989
# 2 30:39     0.105 
# 3 40:49     0.133 
# 4 50:59     0.269 
# 5 60:69     0.198 
# 6 70:79     0.126 
# 7 80:89     0.0705
```

The key part is `ages[findInterval(runif(n), c_age_probs) + 1]`. I created some uniform distributed numbers and used the cumulated (and normalised) probabilities to get the corresponding age bucket. By doing so I didn't even need to create multiple `case_when`-statements.